# Python. While Loop append txt file name with new file name

Tags: python, text, while-loop, format

Hi i'm trying to use a while loop to format a txt file {0} + 1, while at the same type each time i execute python source.py, it will append + 1 and not reset back to 0 and rewrite over the 7 txt files output. so next execution would be where it left off + 1, i'm not quite sure how do that? any help?

```
    i = 0
    while i < 7:
        i += 1
        random.shuffle(chunks)
        output = ' '.join(chunks)
        f = open("c:\\workspace\\simple\\{0}.txt".format(i), 'w')
        f.write(output)
        f.close()
        if i == 7:
            break
```

Answer (score 1):

you should change this

```
f = open("c:\\workspace\\simple\\{0}.txt".format(i), 'w')
```

to this:

```
f = = open("c:\\workspace\\simple\\{0}.txt".format(i), 'a')
```

the `a` will add a line to the file

Comment: the a only adds read when i already read it in another part of the code. it still rewrites over the 7 txt files, since it never adds +1 so it would be 8 and then 16 everytime i execute.